# android: assigning a constant value to a xml-element

Tags: android, xml, constants, android-xml

I'm currently programming an android app. There I am stuck with xml-layout.
Is it possible to assign a value to an xml-tag using a variable (constant) defined in a class?

i have a class called Constants.java for all my program constants. i do this for better maintainability.
now i would like to use one of this constants, e.g. VAL as defined below as value for an ui-widged.

```
public class Constants {
public static final int VAL = 10;
...
}
```

in my case, the widget is a progressbar (horizontal style) and i would like to define the "android:max" value.
normally one can write:

```
android:max="10"
android:max="@Integer/val
```

but i would like to use the value defined in my Constants class, something like:

```
android:max="Constants.VAL"
```

is there a solution for that?

thanks

Comment: I don't think if it possible or not, but I use strings.xml for such a purposes. It is used in the same manner as yours Constants class.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, you can't. Constant values in classes are only available at runtime, and the XML files are compiled and generated before runtime.

The next-best thing to do is declare the XML constants you want to use in `res/values/integers.xml`. Here's an example `integers.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="max">10</integer>
</resources>
```

to use this value in your XML, do this:

```
<YourComponent
    android:yourattr="@integer/max"/>
```

Comment: If constant values are only available at runtime, how can we write `layout_height="match_parent"`, since `match_parent` is a constant?

Answer (score 8):

It's possible using [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

The class should look something like this:

```
class Constants extends BaseObservable {

    private static final int MY_INT = 10;

    @Bindable
    public int getMyInt() {
        return MY_INT;
    }
}
```

and the xml like this:

```
<layout
    ...
    >
    <data>
        <variable
            name="constants"
            type="your.package.Constants" />
    </data>

...

<YourComponent
    android:max='@{constamts.myInt}'

...

</layout>
```

- Don't forget to set the binding itself (`binding.setConstants(constants)`).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, what do you want to do with that?
If you want to use a constant value then just create the ui-widgets with the constants and just ignore the xml.

Comment: i rephrased the question for better understandability.
i don't wan't to hardcode the value into the xml-file for maintainability-reasons.